# JWT authentication filter not being triggered in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a JWT authentication filter for my Spring Rest backend. Creating a JWT doesn't appear to be an issue, however with my current setup, any request is authenticated, no request triggers a 401 despite the fact that the client is not passing any tokens in the header.

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler,
                         final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
    this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/api")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()

            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

/**
 * Sets security evaluation context.
 *
 * @return {@link SecurityEvaluationContextExtension}
 */
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
}
```

I have set this up such that all requests require authorisation. My JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint is as expected: a generic 401 error being thrown.

My  JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain
        filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.debug("Filtering request for JWT header verification");

    try {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            String username = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    (userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    logger.debug("Attempting to get token from request header");

    String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some filter management required in my web.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had to include a reference to the filter in my web.xml file, this isn't picked up automatically using component scanner.

something like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.path.to.JwtFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred due to adding some `additional filters` into the **web.xml** file in the tomcat **conf** path. After removing that filters the authentication will be worked.

If you can't find the additional filters, better to try with a new tomcat or replace the web.xml file with **default** values.